# Signing up but bouncing off before payment gateway

Tags: seo, e-commerce, user-experience

Hi I built a website where people can signup for a membership and then there after they are redirected to the payment gateway. The problem is we are getting a lot of registrations but it seems that 50% of our users are simply not following through on payment - so their database entry stays on Pending Payment. What would cause people to bounce off ?

Comment: normal to get a fair % of abandoned baskets. Offer easy payment methods and consider chasing those who didnt complete. http://www.salecycle.com/cart-abandonment-stats/

Comment: What is the payment gateway, and does it require the user to redirect to another page? If the page the payment gateway displays isn't very professional that could be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a tool like [Inspectlet](https://www.inspectlet.com). They offer *Visitor Recordings* where you can watch users interact with your website in realtime to find any potential flaws in usability.

They offer a [free plan](https://www.inspectlet.com/signup/free) that includes 100 recordings a month on one website.